ReadTimeoutException on webflux POST request but data on the wire is received
I have a WebClient configured as follows:
        webClient = webClientBuilder
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                        HttpClient.create().responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).wiretap(true)
                ))
                    .build();


Using the same client, I do two posts in a row in a test, like this, with just slightly different headers and body contents:
return webClient
            .post()
            .uri(ENDPOINT_PATH, Collections.emptyMap())
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_TYPE_BASIC + " " + authorization)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
            .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(body))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
                block();

The list of headers and the body contents are the only things that vary, between the two calls.
In tests, everything works perfectly.
However, when the application is running - it handles events from a queue synchronously, so no chance of interference with webflux threads there, as far as I can tell - one call succeeds and the other regularly fails. I can see that the endpoint being called sends a response for both calls, using tcpdump. Tcpdump also shows me that the response is a 200 OK response with JSON in the body and a Content-type: application/json header.
The root exception I receive, for the failing call, is a ReadTimeoutException, although the response from the endpoint is in both cases almost instantaneous, from what tcpdump shows, and I also set a response timeout of 5 seconds on the web client when I create it.
If I run the application in a debugger, set a breakpoint just before the failing call is executed, and, when hitting that breakpoint, I copy all call parameters, replace them in the test, then stop the application before the call is performed and instead run the test, everything works fine.
The call chain from fetching the event from the hazelcast queue to the POST performed by the WebClient consists solely of several synchronous calls.
What I also did was a re-implementation of the http calls using RestTemplate, like so:
// rest template instantiation
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .rootUri(ssoConfigUrl)
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                    .build();

// http calls
        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new MultiValueMapAdapter<>(new HashMap<>());
        body.put(QUERY_GRANT_TYPE, Arrays.asList(GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE));
        body.put(QUERY_CLIENT_ID, Arrays.asList(clientId));
        body.put(QUERY_CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(clientSecret));
        body.put(QUERY_SCOPE, Arrays.asList(clientId + AUTH_SCOPE_PARAM_VALUE));
        body.put(QUERY_CODE, Arrays.asList(authorizationCode));
        body.put(QUERY_REDIRECT_URI, Arrays.asList(entraredirectUrl));
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_TYPE_BASIC + " " + authorization);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> tokenResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(tokenEndpoint, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

Using RestTemplate both calls work both from tests and from the running application. However, since I already use webflux elsewhere in the application, I'd rather not mix in RestTemplate.
I have no idea what further to do to diagnose the problem. Anybody any idea what its source might be and what I could do to fix it?
